# Apache Tika-Core BodyContentHandler and Parser is always empty

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

Changed from tika-app-1.1 to tika-core-2.6.0 because of the vulnerabilities of the former. I only want to use the parsers and some other tools included in tika-core.
I need to get the length of the content of the parsed file:

```
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("test1.pdf");
if (documentByteArrayInput != null) {
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    BodyContentHandler handler= new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    AutoDetectParser parser= new AutoDetectParser();
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
    String doc= handler.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    int charsNo= doc.length();
}
```

With the tika-app-1.1 it correctly returns the number of characters of the file.

When testing with tika-core-2.6.0 it always returns 0 as a result. I saw that `handler` was empty every time.

Checked all the dependencies for tika-core-2.6.0.

Are there any compatibility issues between the two? or what can be the cause of that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Include some of the Tika Parsers as well?

Comment: I have included tika-parses-standard-package as well. Do I need another to also include?

Comment: See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika for how to check which ones you correctly included

Comment: I agree with @Gagravarr.  Separately, why switch from tika-app 1.x to tika-core 2.x?  Give tika-app 2.x a try, no?

Comment: Yes, I tried tika-app-2.6.0 and worked. I was hesitant because of potential vulnerabilities from other libraries and didn't want to include components that are not of any use in my case.